# How to use AWS WAF to block certain URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I am trying to use AWS WAF to block requests with certain URL patterns.  I am using the string matching filter, but it is not blocking the requests.  I must be doing it incorrectly.

Here is what I am trying to block:
https://xxx.domain.com/

A *good* url would be:
https://xxx.domain.com/something/something

The URL with nothing after the .com slash is never used in this example and is only hit by malicious traffic.

How do I use WAF to block these requests?

Comment: *"I am using the string matching filter"*  How are you configuring it?  Matching `URI` against `/` should block these requests.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can configure [rules based](https://medium.com/p/70b3b4e0b0e2) on Referrer or Origin
2. Use [regex based rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRegexPatternSet.html) example *.domain.com
3. Take action to Block

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same issue and did it in the following way:

Create a custom rule, which blocks on complete string equality, and setting the match string to /.

This blocks all requests to the base domain url ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).